# Webservices on iPhone using Wsdl2Objc?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, soap

I have recently downloaded the most recent build of this awesome tool `WSDL2OBJC` from google code here: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

After a bit of tweaking and downloading the latest version of the trunk from the svn repo I got a version that created the code for a WSDL I am using and compiles great and actually installs on my phone!

However, I'm not doing anything with it yet, because I am not really sure how to. There is very little in the way of sample code on the site, and there is a sample file in the project if you download it, but again it is very complicated and there are no real bits of documentation.

Has anyone managed to successfully use this stuff? It seems SOOO powerful and useful but from a look around the Internet, no one knows how to use it. We (all) would love someone who has figured it out to post a simple project or detailed walk-through of implementing this so we can put the code that lots of people have worked hard on to good use.

If anyone has found a blog entry or has this information it would be great to see!

I am totally stuck... with no errors. I would love to know how to use this now that it's all compiled successfully!

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223199/using-soap-web-services-in-iphone-with-wsdl2objc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a short tutorial: http://brismith66.blogspot.com/2010/05/iphone-development-accesing-soap.html  I hope it's helpful.